# Replacing the contents of a list of items using regular expressions

Tags: regex, vbscript

Given the following string:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla rhoncus ipsum a eros tincidunt ultricies...

[menu]
item 1|http://stackoverflow.com/1
item 2|http://stackoverflow.com/2
item 3|http://stackoverflow.com/3
[/menu]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla rhoncus ipsum a eros tincidunt ultricies...
```

I'm trying to generate a regular expression that returns:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla rhoncus ipsum a eros tincidunt ultricies...

<ul>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/1">Item 1</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/2">Item 2</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/3">Item 3</a>
</ul>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla rhoncus ipsum a eros tincidunt ultricies...
```

There could be one or more menu blocks in each string and an unknown number of links within each block. I'm able to swap the whole block, but falling over on replacing the individual links within a block.

Is there a way of doing this in one or more regular expressions (I would prefer to avoid splitting the string into an array if at all possible). I'm using vbScript, but a generic example would be just as useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (a bit complicated) way to do it:

```
Option Explicit

Dim g_reItem ' sorry, must be global

Class cReMagic
  Private m_reMenu
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_reMenu = New RegExp
    m_reMenu.Global     = True
    m_reMenu.IgnoreCase = True
    m_reMenu.MultiLine  = True
    m_reMenu.Pattern    = "^\[menu\]([\s\S]+?)^\[/menu\]$"
    Set g_reItem = New RegExp
    g_reItem.Global     = True
    g_reItem.IgnoreCase = True
    g_reItem.MultiLine  = True
' item 1|http://stackoverflow.com/1
' <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/1">Item 1</a>
    g_reItem.Pattern    = "^\s*([^|]+)\|(http:.+?)(\r)$"
  End Sub
  Public Function Replace(sInp)
    Replace = m_reMenu.Replace(sInp, GetRef("MenuRpl"))
  End Function
End Class

Function MenuRpl(sM, sG1, nPos, sSrc)
  MenuRpl = "<ul>" & g_reItem.Replace(sG1, GetRef("ItemRpl")) & "</ul>"
End Function

Function ItemRpl(sM, sG1, sG2, sG3, nPos, sSrc)
  ItemRpl = vbCrLf & "<a href=""" & sG2 & """>" & sG1 & "</a>"
End Function

  Dim sInp : sInp = Join(Array( _
       "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte" _
     , "" _
     , "[menu]" _
     , "item 1|http://stackoverflow.com/1" _
     , "item 2|http://stackoverflow.com/2" _
     , "item 3|http://stackoverflow.com/3" _
     , "[/menu]" _
     , "" _
     , "[mune]" _
     , "item 1|http://stackoverflow.com/1" _
     , "item 2|http://stackoverflow.com/2" _
     , "item 3|http://stackoverflow.com/3" _
     , "[/mune]" _
     , "[menu]" _
     , "item 4|http://stackoverflow.com/4" _
     , "[/menu]" _
     , "" _
     , "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte" _
  ), vbCrLf)
  WScript.Echo sInp
  WScript.Echo "------------------"

  Dim oReMagic : Set oReMagic = New cReMagic
  WScript.Echo oReMagic.Replace(sInp)
  WScript.Echo "------------------"
```

output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte

[menu]
item 1|http://stackoverflow.com/1
item 2|http://stackoverflow.com/2
item 3|http://stackoverflow.com/3
[/menu]

[mune]
item 1|http://stackoverflow.com/1
item 2|http://stackoverflow.com/2
item 3|http://stackoverflow.com/3
[/mune]
[menu]
item 4|http://stackoverflow.com/4
[/menu]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte
------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte

<ul>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/1">item 1</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/2">item 2</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/3">item 3</a>
</ul>

[mune]
item 1|http://stackoverflow.com/1
item 2|http://stackoverflow.com/2
item 3|http://stackoverflow.com/3
[/mune]
<ul>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/4">item 4</a>
</ul>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte
------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. Am I correct in understanding that the scope of the second replace is limited to the output of the first i.e. there shouldn't be any leakage into areas where the same (item) pattern might be used?

Comment: @notreadbyhumans - yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Pseudo]
```

Assuming a few things:

```
-It is always going to be urls between the menus
-You want the end of each to be item [position]
-Each item starts with item[number]
```

My advice to you would be to take this step by step:

1. Find each `menu]` and replace with `ul]` which should be easy enough
2. Put each item into a collection e.g. an array, you can do this by putting every match of the following regex into the array.   `item\s?\d.*`
3. Loop through each item in the array and for each item replace the match of `item\s?\d` with `<a href="` and then just concat onto the end of the string `">Item [array position(plus 1 if of zero index)]</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `/(.+)\|(.+)/` as your regex and then `<a href="$2">$1</a>` as your replacement to get the items...

Then just use a normal string replace to change `[menu]` and `[/menu]`

Comment: The problem is that that pattern is used elsewhere so I can't just do a global replace on it. I need a way of saying 'within the context of [menu] replace these items'.